# How can I handle an AJAX create request in rails without an extra view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to handlers_url }
  format.js { render @handler, layout: false }
end
```

In my handlers.coffee file:

```
$ ->
  $('body').on 'ajax:error', '#new_handler', (event, data, status, error) ->
    console.log error

  $('body').on 'ajax:complete', '#new_handler', (event, data, status) ->
    console.log status
    $('#new_handler').remove()
    $(data.responseText).prependTo('tbody')
```

On the surface, this works in that the data (rendered using the _handler.html.erb file) is appended to the tbody element. But it won't work if I change ajax:complete to ajax:success, and the ajax:error fires every time with:

```
parsererror
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)
```

It looks like the error is because I'm rendering HTML from the _handler.html.erb template and jQuery is expecting pure JS. But I'm not sure how to send pure JS without using a separate create.js.coffee file, which I'm trying to avoid.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish that in the controller without creating the extra javascript view?

Comment: Why don't you just respond with `format.json` instead since you are handling the ajax request yourself and using the conventional rails way.

Comment: @MohamedOsama - I suppose I could, but then I'd have to build the html for displaying the new `@handler` from scratch. I was hoping to just use the _handler.html.erb file for that part.

Comment: If you respond with js it will always cause an Internal Server Error (500) if it could not find a create.js.erb file even if it was empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a .js.erb partial or file to handle the format.js response. You could copy the code from your current html partial and then use a jquery/javascript append/prepend/before method to place the generated HTML wherever you need to.